# D3D11/C++ Inaccuracies in uv interpolation in pixel shader. How to avoid?

Tags: c++, directx11, hlsl, uv-mapping

I'm trying to draw a quad with a texture onto the screen such that texels and pixels perfectly align. Sounds pretty easy. I draw 2 triangles (as TRIANGLE_LIST, so 6 vertices) using these shaders:

```
struct VSOutput
{
    float4 position     : SV_POSITION;
    float2 uv           : TEXCOORD0;
};

VSOutput VS_Draw(uint index : SV_VertexId)
{
    uint vertexIndex = index % 6;
    // compute face in [0,0]-[1,1] space
    float2 vertex = 0;
    switch (vertexIndex)
    {
        case 0: vertex = float2(0, 0);  break;
        case 1: vertex = float2(1, 0);  break;
        case 2: vertex = float2(0, 1);  break;
        case 3: vertex = float2(0, 1);  break;
        case 4: vertex = float2(1, 0);  break;
        case 5: vertex = float2(1, 1);  break;
    }
    // compute uv
    float2 uv = vertex;
    // scale to size
    vertex = vertex * (float2)outputSize;
    vertex = vertex + topLeftPos;
    // convert to screen space
    VSOutput output;
    output.position = float4(vertex / (float2)outputSize * float2(2.0f, -2.0f) + float2(-1.0f, 1.0f), 0, 1);
    output.uv = uv;
    return output;
}

float4 PS_Draw(VSOutput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    uint2 pixelPos = (uint2)(input.uv * (float2)outputSize);
    // output checker of 4x4
    return (((pixelPos.x >> 2) & 1) ^ ((pixelPos.y >> 2) & 1) != 0) ? float4(0, 1, 1, 0) : float4(1, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

where `outputSize` and `topLeftPos` are constants and expressed in pixel units.

Now for outputSize = (102,12) and topLeftPos = (0,0) I get (what I would expect):

[image: Output for x=0, y=0]

But for outputSize = (102,12) and topLeftPos = (0,0.5) I get:

[image: Output for x=0, y=0.5]

As you can see there is a uv-discontinuity where the two triangles connect and interpolation of uv is inaccurate. This basically happens (in x and y) only at positions around the .5 (actually below .49 it correctly snaps to texel 0 and above .51 it snaps correctly to texel 1, but in between I get this artifact).

Now for the purpose I need this for it is essential to have pixel perfect mapping.
Can anyone enlighten me why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

In theory it should not happen but because of the way the GPU rasterizes triangle lines there are some rounding errors on this particular GPU that differ between the texture coordinates and the pixel coordinates.

Texture coordinates does not use the same precision as the vertex coordinates, add to this perspective correction (even though the triangles are flat on screen) plus the way float numbers work and you get those pixel wiggles.

It could also be a loss of precision or difference in precision in the GPU's sub-pixel accuracy calculation of both vertex and texture coordinates.

[image]

Different GPUs and drivers will give different results.

Try changing the `output.position` line by adding floor() :

```
output.position = float4(floor(vertex) / (float2)outputSize * float2(2.0f, -2.0f) + float2(-1.0f, 1.0f), 0, 1));
```

This will remove the fractions of pixels and fix the rounding errors on most GPU/Drivers.

Comment: Well, but even if it would be a precision problem, I don't see how starting from equal positions and uvs it can result in a shearing of the texture. it may be shifted by pixels, but equally everywhere - so no shearing is to be expected.

Comment: i cannot really use the floor idea, because in the final shader, the quad can be rotated. basically i wanna make sure that the texel ends up on a pixel which is closest to the manually transformed corrdinate for that texel. I use it for a sort of hashing, so i can render all objects and then lookup for each texel the corresponding pixel which other texels share this pixel.

Comment: You can rotate the quad and still round its vertices down to pixel integers. Or you can use 2 shaders, one for non-rotated quads and one for rotated. You won't see a tear when the quad is rotated as everything will be unaligned. The other way to fix this that will prevent any tear is to use a single oversized triangle to draw the rectangle with a transparent area but this will make the GPU render twice as much (half of it will be transparent) and might still end up cut in parts inside the GPU when clipped by the screen boundaries.

Comment: There is shearing because of the diagonal split where 2 triangles make 1 rectangle.
The interpolation of the diagonal has fractions of pixels. Pixel coordinates get interpolated one way in the GPU and texture coordinates get interpolated by a different system inside the GPU. This causes the tear you see due to rounding difference in both interpolations.

Comment: When rotating the vertices and rounding them to nearest int that will corrupt any subpixel correctness so that's not an option. I would have thought that the interpolation of uv works by computing gradients in x and y direction (in whatever precision) and using these to interpolate. These gradients should be the same for both triangles, so it's not entirely clear why that shearing artifact arises. I can try the suggested single triangle version, though. Maybe that helps.

Comment: To clarify what I wanna do, and why it is so important for me to have exact rendering: Basically I draw a bunch of these quads into a buffer using the objects position and angle (one quad for each object in my 2d scene, and a buffer with the size of my "world"), such that for each pixel in the world I know which texel of which object it is occupied by. After that I compute for each texel of each object its world position and read from that buffer to see which texels of which other objects it may overlap/collide with, so it must have been rendered to the proper pixel in that buffer.

Comment: @XorTdsc Rasterization precision is moot in this case since vertices are snapped to 1/512 of a pixel before rasterization begins, so you could end up with entire sections of the render target that are logically contained by the quad but don't end up running at all.  Your best bet is to pad out the size of the quad, then do some manual analysis inside the pixel shader yourself to whatever precision you feel necessary, or just accept some inaccuracies in your collision detection algorithm.

Comment: The gradients are not the same **because the interpolation is done on the left edge of each triangles** then a width for the **horizontal pixel scanline fill** is calculated. One edge is vertical, one edge is diagonal: different interpolation results between this **diagonal edge** and the **vertical edge + width** due to accumulated rounding errors.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on how triangles are rasterized (drawn) http://joshbeam.com/articles/triangle_rasterization/

Comment: Well, that helps. Thank you. How about this one then: Is it instead possible to reliably and accurately determine the position (int x, int y) the current pixel is rendered to in the pixelshader ? This way I think I can do a workaround.

Comment: Use gl_FragCoord (https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Built-in_Variable_%28GLSL%29#Fragment_shader_inputs)

Comment: I'm using HLSL. Is there an equivalent ? Simply SV_Position ? And will it not suffer from any of these sorts of jittering ? Because they are in homogenous screen space and i need to convert them to actual pixel positions.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry: its `SV_Position` in HLSL (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn166865.aspx)